# UnixTimestamp Users Last Seen

Tags: php, timestamp

I am trying to create a query to grab the users seen in the last 20 minutes, but it is not fetching the correct results. The row "last_seen" contains a time stamp in which the user last loaded a page.

> mysql_query ("SELECT user,rank,ipaddress FROM `" . SQL_PREFIX .
>   "site_session` WHERE last_seen > ".strtotime("-30 minutes")." order by
>   user desc");

Comment: So what is it fetching? Other than the last 30 mins, not 20.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT user,rank,ipaddress 
FROM " . SQL_PREFIX . "site_session 
WHERE last_seen > INTERVAL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 20 MINUTE
order by user desc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using a Unix timestamp, why not just use math?

```
SELECT ... WHERE last_seen > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (60*20)
```

If you're column is a `datetime`, then youse:

```
SELECT ... WHERE last_seen > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)
```

You also need to stop using `mysql_` functions in new code. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mysql_query ("SELECT user,rank,ipaddress FROM " . SQL_PREFIX . "site_session WHERE last_seen > ".time()-1200." order by user desc");
```

time() is a php function, not mysql

Comment: `time()` is used for extracting the `time` from a `datetime`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php time returns the current time as timestamp!!! and my code works!

Comment: beacuse you are using a sql function, i am using a php function.. not correct to downvote my answer! just another aproach that also works!

Comment: You are indeed correct; Please make an edit to your answer so I can remove my downvote. I would also recommend you point out that the OP does not use `mysql_` functions.

Comment: omg... http://php.net/manual/it/function.strtotime.php strtotime is a phpfunction. you can replace this with time()-1200 and php will put a numeric value to this, and then send off the query with the numeric value already in it. (in my previous post i meant mysql, no sql)

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you?

Comment: Re-read my comment. I can't remove the downvote unless you make an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`mysql_query ("SELECT user,rank,ipaddress FROM " . SQL_PREFIX . "site_session WHERE last_seen > (NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) order by user desc");`